# Reach layer name property from a layer group in OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, web, gis, openlayers-3

I have a layer group consisting of 3 layers and named for example: `group1`.

I want to produce an array of the names of the layers that are in this group. I'm actually doing that:

`group1.getLayers().getArray()`

I'm reaching the level of the `ol.layer.vector`, but I can't seem to find how to access the value of the name propertie.

My guess was to do add a `.get("name")` after the getArray() but it doesn't work (I guess you can't call more than 2 methods). I also tried stocking the results of the getArray() in a variable, but then I can't do a get("name") on the variable.

How can I access my layers name ?

Edit: Looks like I can use the `getLayersArray()` method also, but I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: If you can get the results of getArray() in a variable, can you not just access that variable directly? Or iterate through it to access its contents?

Comment: @1saac what is stocked in the variable is a ol.layer.vector structure. I can't iterate in it because it has a length of 1. Or maybe I don't know exactly how to iterate through such strucutre

Comment: Found the way to get the name and posted the answer, thanks to you @1saac !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found my answer.

```
function getNames(dom){
    var stock = [];
    var layer_names = [];
    stock = dom.getLayersArray();

    for(i=0;i<stock.length;i++){
        layer_names[i] = stock[i].get("name");
    };
    return layer_names;
}
```

Thanks to @1saac .

Edit: Pushed it a little to add properties keys of each layer:

```
function getNames(domaine){
        var r_stock = [];
        var r_layers = [];
        r_stock = domaine.getLayersArray();

        for(i=0;i<r_stock.length;i++){

            feat_source = r_stock[i].getSource();
            feat_get = feat_source.getFeatures();
            prop_feature[i] = feat_get[0].getKeys();

            r_layers[i] = ["name", r_stock[i].get("name")];

            for(j=0;j<prop_feature[i].length;j++){
                r_layers[i].push("id" + j, prop_feature[i][j])
            };

        };

        return r_layers;
    };
```